# visual studio 2022 17.4.3 Fake Error in razor (blazor) page

Tags: visual-studio

in visual studio 2022 in blazor project i have fake error in all element bind
[image]

my project build and run and publish successfully ... but this error existed everywhere ...
how i fix it ?

Error :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error (active)  RZ9989  The attribute '@bind' was matched by multiple bind attributes. Duplicates:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.BindAttributes
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.BindAttributes      \Pages\CacheManagementPaymentSystems\ReportDaily.razor  84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in visual studio 17.4.4 the problem fixed

Answer (score -1):

I did not have it until 17.4.4 now I do...

Comment: Seems the same as already accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75091950/9193372). Right?

Comment: 17.5 is out ...

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You should have make it as a comment

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33895856)